# Running TRACE32 using python

Tags: python, trace32

I want to run a .cmm file that reads the register values in kernel in TRACE32 and i want to initiate that using python so that data analysis becomes easy. Kindly help me with the procedure and commands to do so

Answer (score 1):

What you intend is to read register values from target under test in Trace32 using python, correct me if 
I am wrong.

If my understanding is right, then what you intend can be achieved. api_remote.pdf help document can be found in the installation folder of Trace32. In this document hlinknet.c and hremote.c files are mentioned which provide Trace32 API's for controlling Trace32 from external application which can be developed in python, Labview or any other programming language. You can create suitable commands in python that call trace32 API's and generate your own application in python to control Trace32.

I am not aware of how to develop in python but the above reference will get you what you want to achieve using python if I understood your question correctly.